# Python code execution bottleneck due to SSL - How to optimimze?

Tags: python-3.x, optimization

I would like to improve the performance of a Python script and have been using cProfile to generate a performance report:

```
ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
   75   23.514    0.314   23.514    0.314 {method 'read' of '_ssl._SSLSocket' objects}
   75    8.452    0.113    8.452    0.113 {method 'do_handshake' of '_ssl._SSLSocket' objects}
   75    2.113    0.028    2.113    0.028 {method 'load_verify_locations' of '_ssl._SSLContext' objects}
   75    1.479    0.020    1.479    0.020 {method 'connect' of '_socket.socket' objects}
```

Example code:

```
import requests
import json
from collections import defaultdict

#Added for multiprocessing
from urllib.request import urlopen
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool 

results = defaultdict(list)

# Make the Pool of workers
pool = ThreadPool(4)

# Open the urls in their own threads
# and return the results
results = pool.map(urlopen, requests.post())

  #close the pool and wait for the work to finish
pool.close()
pool.join()

for store, data in results.items():
    print('Store: {}'.format(store), end=', ')
    if data:
        for inventory in data:
            print(inventory)
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to [so]! This particular Question rather belongs to the sibling board codereview.stackexchange.com! Check [what's on topic here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)!

Answer (score 1):

You are effectively measuring the response time of remote websites, which is probably not what you want. In order to maximize the throughput (the number of HTTP requests sent or data received per second) you should send many simultaneous requests asynchronously. You can use an async HTTP library like [aiohttp](http://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) or just the native Python asyncio/asyncore.

Comment: I've added example code above. I'll have to research aiohttp - I'm not familiar with that, or how to modify my code to send multiple requests at once.

Comment: The simplest thing you can do is run multiple threads doing requests.post(). It is not as efficient as asynchronous requests, but it still can speed you up tens of times. BTW, don't hammer _a_single_ Web site at full speed, your IP can be blocked if you generate too much load. A good spider polls multiple Web sites, with each one receiving a slow stream of requests.

Comment: I have attempted to add multiprocessing/threads based on examples but am running into roadblocks since I couldn't find examples using loops. Any pointers would be appreciated (additions to code are commented above). Thanks